# Spring Cloud @StreamListener doesn't provide an Acknowledgement header even auto-commit set to false

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm currently stuck in a simple example of manually managing Kafka offsets and commits. I have an application with Spring Cloud Streams which sets `enable.auto.commit = false` (seen on the startup log when printing ConsumerValues), but still, when I parse the message it doesn't provide an acknowledgement header.

This is my listener:

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handleSchedulerMessage(@Payload SchedulerEvent event, @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    log.debug("[message={}]", event);
    // todo: processing
    log.debug("Event processed successfully [event={}]", event);
}
```

The YAML for configuration is also very simple:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: scheduler
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: *kafka-broker*:9092
          zkNodes: *zookeeper*:2181
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: scheduler
          contentType: application/json
          consumer:
            autoCommitOffset: false
```

And when I send a message, an error immediately pops up:

```
2018-05-22 11:38:32.470 ERROR 11651 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'kafka_acknowledgment' for method parameter type [interface org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[38], headers={kafka_offset=9, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@fdac355, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=scheduler, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1526981909241, contentType=application/json}]
```

The received message doesn't contain the desired header, opposed as what the documentation says when autoCommit is disabled:

```
Whether to autocommit offsets when a message has been processed. If set to false, a header with the key kafka_acknowledgment of the type org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment header will be present in the inbound message. Applications may use this header for acknowledging messages.
```

The code is not complex, and I'm not using any pre-generated project. Examples don't explain more than what I have done, so I don't know what I could be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you lose one level of indents in your YAML.

According docs the property must be like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
```

But your sample is like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
```

Pay attention in the extra `.kafka.` in the middle.

I don't know how to help to manage YAML properly, but that is what we have to have to make it working.